# SQLite Optimization (Python) : Finding duplicate entries, and then consolidating referenced values to a representative unique entry?

Tags: python, sqlite

My problem is as follows:

I have a list of entries in a file that is analogous to names and addresses in a phone book. This list is unordered, somewhere on the order of 1-10 billion entries long, and occupies 500gb on disk. I'd like to count how many times each name is represented in this file (i.e., how many duplicates there are for each name), and then concatenate all known addresses to that name.

My first approach was to insert the entries with a try/except clause, and update if necessary (UPSERT?):

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTable (Name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Address TEXT) WITHOUT ROWID')
try:
    c.execute(f'INSERT INTO MYTable (Name, Address) VALUES ("{thename}","{theaddress}"')
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    c.execute(f'UPDATE MYTable SET Address = Address || "{theaddress}" WHERE Name = "{thename}"')
```

And this performs the job at a rate of about 50,000 rows/s. However, I'm trying to make it go faster, as it will take about 50-60 hours to create the database with this approach. I've tried the following optimization attempts:

- PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL  ; little effect
- PRAGMA synchrounous = off ; little effect
- beginning transactions/committing transactions manually ; little effect
- Removing the index, using executemany, adding the index back on, and then using the fast searches to find duplicates; ~2-4x faster to create the initial DB, but preserves the duplicates until they can be indexed and then collapsed into a single (name:address1,address2,address_n) representation. Also occupies a lot of space on disk.

Is there something about either the approach I should change, or some optimization to solve this issue? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does trying the `UPDATE` first and only doing the `INSERT` if the row is not found go faster? (I have no idea how many collisions you expect to find…)

Comment: why not sort the list first if you're on a *nix machine? using `parallel` or `xargs` you can chomp through this pretty fast

Comment: Taking a step back, are you sure this is the right approach? Instead of concatenating together a bunch of addresses into a single address field for the name, why not have a unique table with the names, then a one-to-many table with as many separate address rows as needed to associate with each name? (And of course for your bulk load, you can turn off any checking on the foreign key, and then turn it back on after the zillions of entries are created.)

Comment: ^^ this is a good approach as well, make a table with unique names and then you can just join on the names

Comment: Even if you _do_ ultimately need the data denormalized, it may be faster to first load up the normalized tables, then add an `Address` column to the first table, then update the first table to set each `Address` to the concatenation of all addresses from the other table with the same name,

Comment: @eagle How are you going to use `xargs` or `parallel` to sort 10 billion values?

Comment: @abarnert, `sort` has a parallel flag you can enable, plus you can specify how much you want to buffer in memory

Comment: @eagle But what is `xargs` going to do for you? Are you going to feed 10 billion values into `xargs` to pass them to separate `sort` invocations and then merge them all together with another `sort` or something?

Comment: One more thing: if you really do want a denormalized table that just maps single unique names to single (concatenated) address values… why not just use a NoSQL key-value store instead of a relational database?

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions - let me answer them:


Re: update first, I haven't tried as I haven't gotten a good sense of collisions yet, but this may indeed speed it up

Re: the approach, I'm not sure it's right at all! So I needed to bounce ideas around. I have been trying to avoid the 1:many approach to reduce table size in the end. The actual product is estimated to be ~1 TB final.

Re: parallel sorting - sounds interesting, but I'm on a Windows machine and trying to stick the python standard library for this task